# What is the connection/relationship between Datanodes in HDFS and node manager on Yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am reading the basics about Yarn and Hadoop FileSystem. I was told by some blogs online that Yarn is just resource management system and HDFS is about storage. But I encountered the following lines in the book Hadoop Definitive Guide:
[image]
In this line, I can infer that there should be some connection between the location of Datanodes and Node Manager Node. Maybe they can be in the same place. That contradicts the knowledge I got from the blog.
Can anyone helps to explain this?

I googled a lot by"connection between Datanode and Node Manager" and I can not find direct answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

Yarn is the OS, the compute power.
HDFS is the Disk.

If beneficial to move the compute to a node where the data is located.  A node will often have a node manager that manages the compute(yarn) and a data node(HDFS).  So both a container, and files for a yarn/hadoop job, can be colocated on 1 node/server.  It's also the case you can just have a node manager on a node that isn't a data node.  And you could have a data node, that wasn't a nodemanager.  The two are independent, but frequently it makes sense to collocate them, to take advantage of data locality. After-all who wants a OS without a disk?  (Their is actually a use case for this but lets not get into "compute nodes")